# How to create a csv file in unix

Tags: shell, unix, csv

I have to create one `csv` file for 1st day of every month with `two columns` with headings `Date` and `Count`.

Another script runs daily and it finds the particular matched string of log entities in all log files and those log entities, count of those matched log entities count to be inserted into another file. I acheived this...

But now, I need to insert Date and Count into the csv file. Every day the csv file needs to be updated whenever the script runs.

Can you please show me how to i achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to write the two words " Date" and "Count" into a CSV file, which is easy `echo Date,Count > file.csv`, or do you mean you need to calculate the date and calculate a count of something and write that in a file?

Comment: can you share the other script?

Comment: Like Mark Setchell said `echo Date,Count > file.csv` is how you create the header.  If you have a script that outputs the date and the count by parsing log files with a comma in between you just run it with `>> file.csv` at the end to append that data to the csv file.

Comment: You should show the code you already have, and describe where you got stuck. Also you need to specify the format of your date string - in particular, if it possibly can contain a comma or or a double-quote character.

Answer (score 0):

it depend on the other script outpu.

suppose daily running script's output is somethin like this :

```
2014-01-14, 200
```

then simply you can append this to your csv file :

```
./daily_script >> my.csv
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try the following code:

```
spool  file_name.csv;
select 'date,count' from dual ;
select sysdate|| ',' || cnt from table_name;
spool off;
```